# Configure highlight of repeated text in Sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3

When you double click on text, it highlights the current text and then places a thin blue border around repeated text. I want to make this thin blue border thicker and change it to white for easier visibility. Can this be configured? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighting you are referring to is controlled by the `match_selection` preference. I'm just mentioning this here in case it helps others find this Q/A pair in future.

It seems that the color for this is [controlled by the `caret` color in your color scheme](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-change-the-word-highlighting-color/5947). However, it seems that there is no way to change the color without changing the color of the caret, or make the border thicker. There is an open feature request for the latter here: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/453